# How to get the only max row result from duplicate rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have results in table in this format.

[image: Data is in this format]

For this format my query is select distinct channel,location,user_loadtimestamp from [Email_Channels]

I want the results in below format.

[image: Want Result in this format]

Comment: Did you have a look at [`MAX`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/max-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)? What about it didn't you understand or what it didn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want aggregation:

```
select channel, location, max(user_loadtimestamp)
from [Email_Channels]
group by channel, location;
```

Comment: Thanks, I was looking for the exact answer.